# How do i update values of keys inside and object with setSate in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think i don't use enough objects(dictionaries), so i have an issue:
i am using typscript,
i have an object holding all the quantities for each element of a recipe inside a state.
when the user changes the size i want to update those quantities by a factor.
flour2 and oil are optional, every item of this object is a number(their type is being defined somewhere else)

```
const [doughQuantities, setDoughQuantities] = useState({
    flour: doughRecipe.flour.quantity,
    flour2: doughRecipe.flour2?.quantity,
    water: doughRecipe.water.quantity,
    salt: doughRecipe.salt.quantity,
    yeast: doughRecipe.yeast.quantity,
    oil: doughRecipe.oil?.quantity
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (size === 'large') {
      const factor = 1.5
      setDoughQuantities(prev => Object.values(prev).forEach(element =>{
        element = element * factor
      }))
    }
  }, [size])
```

when typing my setState fucntion i get this eslint:

"*Argument of type '(prev: { flour: number; flour2: number | undefined; water: number; salt: number; yeast: number; oil: number | undefined; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ flour: number; flour2: number | undefined; water: number; salt: number; yeast: number; oil: number | undefined; }>'.   Type '(prev: { flour: number; flour2: number | undefined; water: number; salt: number; yeast: number; oil: number | undefined; }) => void' is not assignable to type '(prevState: { flour: number; flour2: number | undefined; water: number; salt: number; yeast: number; oil: number | undefined; }) => { flour: number; flour2: number | undefined; water: number; salt: number; yeast: number; oil: number | undefined; }'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ flour: number; flour2: number | undefined; water: number; salt: number; yeast: number; oil: number | undefined; }'.*"

How does one read and write value of keys inside such an object?

Comment: Aside from your code not working, you are attempting to mutate the state rather than replace it

Comment: @possum should i pass a function to the setState instead, (that returns an object)

Comment: Look at the answer posted.  I correctly creates a new object

Comment: yes i saw that, it creates a new object, but it's the type error that is a problem, the possibly undefined value triggers this? but even if i take it out there is still a typeError saying Object is possibly undefined

Answer (score 1):

You initialized the `state` as an `object` and then modify it to an `array`.

If you want to set an `object` and multiply the `value` of each property by the `factor`.

```
const [doughQuantities, setDoughQuantities] = useState({
    flour: doughRecipe.flour.quantity,
    flour2: doughRecipe.flour2?.quantity,
    water: doughRecipe.water.quantity,
    salt: doughRecipe.salt.quantity,
    yeast: doughRecipe.yeast.quantity,
    oil: doughRecipe.oil?.quantity
  })

useEffect(() => {
    if (size === "large") {
        const factor = 1.5;
        setDoughQuantities((prev) =>
            Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(prev).map(([key, value]) => {
                    return [key, value * factor];
                })
            )
        );
    }
}, [size]);
```

Comment: it gives a type error of :Argument of type '(prev: { flour: number; flour2: number | undefined; water: number; salt: number; yeast: number; oil: number | undefined; }) => { [k: string]: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ flour: number; flour2: number | undefined; water: number; salt: number; yeast: number; oil: number | undefined; }>'. etc